# What is the answer to the following Rebus?

Tags: rebus

What is the answer to the following puzzle?

```
                  T
               H
            G
           I
        F
```

Comment: Are the 'i' and 'g' closer together on purpose?

Comment: I think the answer is: "your puzzle is too broad".

Comment: @Matsmath it's not really that broad if you read the answers, everyone down there basically has the same answer

Comment: @Beasty Gerbil it is not clear to me whether or not you corrected a typo, or an intentional "bump" in the upside hill. I suggest you to check with the OP.

Answer (score 16):

it could be

> fight to the top

or

> put up a fight

or even

> uphill battle

Comment: Those were some great propositions... But i feel like something is missing !!

The characters are actually not normally writing from the bottom to the top. I think there is some hidden meaning after that too !

Answer (score 6):

It is

> [an uphill fight](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/an+uphill+fight)

because

> the letters spell the word "FIGHT",
> if read from bottom (left) to top (right);
> i.e., up a hill.

Answer (score 2):

I think Peregrine Rook has it, but I prefer:

> An uphill struggle

Which is synonymous, but in more common usage at least in the UK.

Answer (score 2):

Using another synonym for fight, it could also be

> Rise to the challenge

That said, I believe Will's final answer of

> uphill battle

is most likely correct because

> If the word was a simple vertical, bottom-to-top, then that would suggest "rise", "put up" etc. Since it's on a slope, it suggests that we're looking for something more gradual, and "uphill" fits that very cleanly.
>
>  Then we're looking for a phrase beginning with "uphill" and ending with a synonym for "fight"; both "battle" and "struggle" work well, and both are fairly common phrases. I wouldn't have a problem with either being correct, but "battle" is a much more direct synonym for "fight", so I'd personally go for "**uphill battle**".

Answer (score 2):

Could be fight, could be a flight of steps, so it kinda looks to me like that classic description of an "adrenaline reaction":

> FIGHT or FLIGHT ???

Answer (score 2):

The rebus is the title of a seminar:

***How to make up a fight on the internet***

Because the poster has made "fight" go up, and has written this in a post on the internet.

Incidentally, step one in this seminar is to post a somewhat ambiguous and possibly incorrectly formatted puzzle on a popular puzzling site and never return to answer any questions.

How meta.